# Can I use Firebase from QML?

Tags: qml, firebase

Qml uses Javascript extensively.

Firebase offers Javascript libraries for browsers.

**Is it possible to use Firebase from QML?**

Any specific details are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QML, being an extension of QT, which is essentially a cross-platform tool for creating desktop/mobile apps, is not a web browser and does not run it's JavaScript-like code in a browser environment.

Thus, it seems highly improbable that you could get Firebase's JavaScript SDK (which expects to be presented with APIs like XmlHttpRequest, WebSocket, a DOM, and iframes) to function appropriately.

Since Firebase does not offer a C++ SDK, it seems like the best approach to accessing Firebase from QML might be to utilize the [REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html) for which a community implementation exists [here](https://github.com/clkasd/qt-firebaseapi).

---

As of end of 2016, a [C++ SDK is now available](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup), mainly aimed to mobile platforms. Currently only a subset of Firebase features are supported by it is in active development and probably some if not all of the missing features will be added.

Comment: Actually QML has [XmlHttpRequest](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-javascript-qmlglobalobject.html#xmlhttprequest) (no same origin enforcement, no synch requests).

Comment: The point isn't that QML can't perform the functions needed by firebase.js, but rather that Firebase is going to expect to be run in a browser and will make assumptions about the tools available. Feel free to give it a test run if you think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to create mobile apps, it is possible to integrate the available native Firebase SDK for Android and iOS in your application.

This solution requires native Java and Obj-C code to work with the SDK. You can then wrap this code with a C++-based type to expose the Firebase SDK features for QML.

This allows a simple usage with QML similar to:

```
FirebaseDatabase {
  id: firebaseDb

  Component.onCompleted: getValue("public/path/to/my/object")

  onReadCompleted: {
    if(success) {
      // parameter "value" can be a nested object/array, as read from your database
      console.debug("Read value " + value.subarray[3].subproperty.text)
    }
  }
}
```

As there's quite some implementation work required, the above example is taken from a ready-made solution by [V-Play Engine](https://v-play.net/). Some more usage examples can be found [here](https://v-play.net/updates/v-play-2-15-0-qt-5-10-qt-creator-4-5-support-firebase-data-structures-and-queries#v-play-firebase-queries-and-data-structures).